# Debugging google.maps.FusionTablesLayer

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Is there any failureCallback when creating a FusionTablesLayer? Is there a way to know if there is a problem with your query? Or how many rows were loaded from the query?

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({ 
       query: {    select: 'address',    
                   from: '198945',
                   where: 'ridership > 5000'  }
 });
```

Comment: So I tried to query the data using: http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=myid and I got this error: Fusion Tables is not available for mydomain. Learn more about Google products you can use with mydomain.  

If you are the Google Apps administrator, please read these articles to learn more about controlling user access to Google Apps services and turning services on/off for certain users.

But when I log into the marketplace, I don't see how to add fusion tables. ( The table is set to full visibility on the web )

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to both your questions is no.
I've relied on the undocumented Fusion Table JSONP support to both easily test queries without worrying about GMap stuff and as well to retrieve the row count from a particular query.

Robin Kraft documented this JSONP approach using jQuery at this blog:

http://www.reddmetrics.com/2011/08/10/fusion-tables-javascript-query-maps.html

As well there has been discussion of this on the old FT API Google Group.

Eric

Comment: The jsonp callback is now officially supported.